# Navigation menu shrink - font color

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I am tyring to change the color of the menu text when the header resizes on scroll.

I have tried the following:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 20) {
    $('ul.art-hmenu>li>a').addClass('shrinkmenufont');
  } else {
    $('ul.art-hmenu>li>a').removeClass('shrinkmenufont');
  }
});
```

with:

```
.shrinkmenufont {
  font-color: black;
}
```

I can see the function is executing, but the color of the font does not change from white to black when the user scrolls down

any tips would be appreciated please

thank you

Link:

[Website](http://agl.run-time.co.za/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues. First, the CSS property to set the colour of text is just `color`, not `text-color`. Secondly, the rule that sets the colour to orange is `ul.art-hmenu > li > a.active`. This has a far higher specificity than just `.shrinkmenufont`, so overrides it. For the black colour to be used you need to make your rule more specific, or the same but placed afterwards. Try this:

```
ul.art-hmenu > li > a.shrinkmenufont {
    color: 'black';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer includes my solution as well as very helpful tips and guidance, thank you

Answer (score 1):

you can add only below css for resize header font color are changed:

CSS:

```
.shrinknav a.shrinkmenufont {
  color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if ($(document).scrollTop() > 20) {
       $('ul.art-hmenu>li>a').css('color', 'black');
   } else {
       $('ul.art-hmenu>li>a').css('color', 'white');
   }
});
```

Comment: You should avoid putting CSS styling in your JS code.

Comment: It works! Then the questioner will decide which one to choose!

Comment: The questioner' **user2502658** "and was **not you**. The question is answered several people including me! Each correct answer! Then the questioner decide which one to use! That's it! For my part thread is closed!

Comment: @AdamP. Calm down. This site is about learning and helping others, which is what I am trying to do - for both you, the OP and anyone else who reads this question in the future. My first comment was guidance about not putting CSS styling in your JS code as it's really bad practice. For example, you see in the DOM that an element has had a style applied, which you can't see in the HTML source, nor in the CSS, so you have to then go trawling through the JS to find it. If you'd like to know more about this research 'Separation of Concerns'.